# Ac signal of soldering iron tip

Tags: ac, soldering

Did you noticed that when holding a LED with bare fingers and connect it to a soldering iron(ac type) it gets a little bright.

I did it for other components to reduce their heat during the soldering. I need to know is it ok to hold IC (ex 74hc595, mcu's, ...) Pins with fingers or metal tools when their other pins are in touch with iron tip?

Is there any reverse current ? May it damage the chip ?

Comment: The leakage may be <1mA is unlikely to damage but the soldering iron ought to be insulated with 1Mohm to earth ground, for ESD protection. Yours may not be,

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 my power outlet did not provide any ground. Atleast i didn't remember any indoor ground-provided outlet in this country

Comment: that's why your LED glows

Comment: It may burn your fingers as heat conducts through the metal, but other than it it's probably fine.

Comment: electric field coupling, from 160 volts peak at 60Hz, thru a few picoFarads of capacitance.